# Add custom FreeGLUT application to Yocto image

Tags: linux, yocto

I am trying to add a simple OpenGL+FreeGLUT application to my Yocto image to run it in Quemu.
I:

1. Cloned yocto and openembedded repositories
2. Added meta-oe layer
3. Created custom layer with my application

```
do_compile() {
    ${CXX} mydemo.cpp ${LDFLAGS} -lGL -lGLU -lglut -o mydemo
}
```

4. Added the line below to build/conf/local.conf:
   `IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " freeglut mydemo"`

When I run `bitbake core-image-sato` the compiler can't find the FreeGLUT header:
`fatal error: GL/freeglut.h: No such file or directory`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed `DEPENDS = "freeglut"` in my *.bb file.